# Summing up in Datatable

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable

I have a datatable like

```
Full Name    ID   7/13/2015    7/14/2014
A             1       20          30
A             2       30          50
B             3       50          70
B             4       60          30
C             5       20          30
C             6       30          80
C             7       10          30
```

I want to Add one more row to this datatable which would consist of the SUM of each person in the specific Date

```
Full Name    ID   7/13/2015    7/14/2014
A             1       20          30
A             2       30          50

A         total       50          80

B             3       50          70
B             4       60          30
C             5       20          30
C             6       30          80
C             7       10          30
```

I Know how to create the new row and to add the name and the ID, but is their any way I can used c# modules to add up the specific sums. I looked up and their is something like table_name.Compute(); but I am getting errors implementing that.

- Note the Column Full Name has the value with a space and the value in that column can contain spaces as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that returns a new `object[]` which matches every row in the given table against the specified value in the given column index.  Rows that match are summed on all other columns, and the sum is returned in the corresponding index.

```
private object[] GetSumRow(DataTable table, string nameToMatchAgainst, int nameColumnIndex = 0)
{
    object[] sumRow = new object[table.Columns.Count];

    IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => r[nameColumnIndex].ToString() == nameToMatchAgainst);
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == nameColumnIndex)
        {
            sumRow[i] = nameToMatchAgainst;
        }
        else
        {
            sumRow[i] = rows.Sum(r => int.Parse(r[i].ToString()));
        }
    }

    return sumRow;
}
```

So calling `var sumRow = GetSumRow(yourExampleTable, "A")` would return `["A", 3, 50, 80]`, which you can then add to the table with `yourExampleTable.Rows.Add(sumRow)`.

Comment: I am not able to understand the above code well enough. Like for each specific name in the Datable A,B,C I need to create a total column for them, for each specific column date. So in the above code how do I specify to takes only values from all names A, and Column 7/13/2015 and all of B for that date and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  The original answer summed an entire column, but didn't filter by the value of another column.  Edited my answer; hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks it makes more sense now.